# Disks have become spare with fake Raid. Is there any change to remount the volume?

Tags: raid, mdadm, fakeraid

I used the Intel Rapid Storage Technology (fake RAID) with 8 disks (6 disks for RAID 5 and 2 hot spares).

```
~# mdadm --detail-platform
       Platform : Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager
        Version : 4.3.0.1018
    RAID Levels : raid0 raid1 raid10 raid5
    Chunk Sizes : 4k 8k 16k 32k 64k 128k
    2TB volumes : supported
      2TB disks : supported
      Max Disks : 8
    Max Volumes : 2 per array, 4 per controller
       Platform : Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager
        Version : 4.3.0.1018
    RAID Levels : raid0 raid1 raid10 raid5
    Chunk Sizes : 4k 8k 16k 32k 64k 128k
    2TB volumes : supported
      2TB disks : supported
      Max Disks : 8
    Max Volumes : 2 per array, 4 per controller
 I/O Controller : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.4 (SATA)
          Port0 : /dev/sda (WD-WMC4M0F1U9V3)
          Port1 : /dev/sdb (WD-WMC4M0F454X9)
          Port2 : /dev/sdc (WD-WCC4M2UY549P)
          Port3 : /dev/sdd (WD-WCC4M6ZS0Y84)
 I/O Controller : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2 (SATA)
          Port0 : /dev/sde (WD-WCC4N2ELDPNU)
          Port1 : /dev/sdf (WD-WCC4M7HPS95S)
          Port2 : /dev/sdg (WD-WCC4N7JKRAZX)
          Port3 : /dev/sdh (WD-WCC4M7NPJ6F6)
          Port4 : - no device attached -
          Port5 : - no device attached -
```

The operating system is Debian 7 and mdadm v3.2.5.

The server shutdown without obvious reasons and the disks have become spare except the first one.

```
~# mdadm --examine --verbose /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 2699cae1
         Family : 2699cae1
     Generation : 0000bc6c
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 0d787829:4de03ecb:ee3fd89b:a6e12bc4
       Checksum : b53c9042 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 6
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WMC4M0F1U9V3
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 3907022862 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

[vol0]:
           UUID : eacdf403:3a692d56:1ab3e890:a8373e9c
     RAID Level : 5
        Members : 6
          Slots : [UUUUUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
     Array Size : 19535114240 (9315.07 GiB 10001.98 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 3907022848 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 15261808
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCC4M7NPJ6F6
          State : active
             Id : 07000000
    Usable Size : 3907022862 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

  Disk02 Serial : WD-WCC4N7JKRAZX
          State : active
             Id : 06000000
    Usable Size : 3907022862 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

  Disk03 Serial : WD-WCC4M7HPS95S
          State : active
             Id : 05000000
    Usable Size : 3907022862 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

  Disk04 Serial : WD-WCC4N2ELDPNU
          State : active
             Id : 04000000
    Usable Size : 3907022862 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

  Disk05 Serial : WD-WCC4M6ZS0Y84
          State : active
             Id : 03000000
    Usable Size : 3907022862 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
```

All the other disks have the following state:

```
~# mdadm --examine --verbose /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.0.00
    Orig Family : 00000000
         Family : 80ba23ff
     Generation : 00000001
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
       Checksum : b60a3585 correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 1
   RAID Devices : 0

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC4M6ZS0Y84
          State : spare
             Id : 03000000
    Usable Size : 3907026958 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)

    Disk Serial : WD-WCC4M6ZS0Y84
          State : spare
             Id : 03000000
    Usable Size : 3907026958 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
```

What I tried:

```
:~# mdadm --assemble --verbose --metadata=imsm /dev/md/imsm0
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md/imsm0
mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md/imsm0, slot -1.
mdadm: added /dev/sda to /dev/md/imsm0 as -1
mdadm: Container /dev/md/imsm0 has been assembled with 1 drive
:~# mdadm -I /dev/md/imsm0 --verbose
mdadm: not enough devices to start the container
```

or to re-assemble the required disks (those in vol0 but I'm pretty sure that was [a-f] in my initial command to create the raid container):

```
:~# mdadm --assemble /dev/md/imsm0 --metadata=imsm /dev/sd[adefgh]
mdadm: Container /dev/md/imsm0 has been assembled with 6 drives
:~# mdadm -I /dev/md/imsm0 --verbose
mdadm: not enough devices to start the container
:~# mdadm --detail --scan /dev/md/imsm0
/dev/md/imsm0:
        Version : imsm
     Raid Level : container
  Total Devices : 6

Working Devices : 6


           UUID : 0d787829:4de03ecb:ee3fd89b:a6e12bc4
  Member Arrays :

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       0       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
       1       8       64        -        /dev/sde
       2       8       80        -        /dev/sdf
       3       8       96        -        /dev/sdg
       4       8      112        -        /dev/sdh
       5       8        0        -        /dev/sda
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/imsm-volumes-in-mdadm-raid-setup-776171/, it appears you do it in two steps, one to create the containers, then another step to mount the devices using the containers.